# Any binary editor to open a file in binary form (1 and 0) NOT HEX?

Tags: text-editor, binary

I want to open a binary files in the form of 0s and 1s. I've found several editors on the internet but all of them display hexadecimal not binary.

Comment: For binary viewer see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/195108/57134 .

Comment: Is there any GUI editor which can do this?

Comment: Why would you *not* want hex? It's the same numbers, just different base.

Answer (score 0):

I found "Jeex" in the "ubuntu software center" it will let you edit in Hex, Binary, Octal, and ASCII.

Its GUI, pretty basic but look like it works. (See image bellow.)

[image: https://s13.postimg.org/wn9mxz7tz/Screenshot_from_2018-02-04_03_27_06.png]